# Is there a way to communicate data from .jsx to .scss file in a CRA based react project?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

I am using Sass as the styling solution for my React web app.

I import a `SomeComponent.scss` file in a `SomeComponent.js` file and use class selectors with BEM naming conventions...

I've been using `clsx` as a means of conditionally rendering different className for variations in styles.

But I would very much like to know if there is a way to tell the style sheet that I would like to use some value for a specific condition.

Using varying classNames for different conditions seem to clutter up my style sheet.

Comment: You can't tell a stylesheet to do scripting. You can however use your script to conditionally use different style in the stylesheet.

Comment: @yqlim Is that one of the reasons why people look for CSS-in-JS type of solutions?

Comment: I personally don't like CSS-in-JS and would opt for using different class names (which is easy provided that you are using BEM). But yeah, I think that's one of the reasons people uses CSS-in-JS.

Comment: @yqlim Thanks for your help! I was wondering this since there are times when you only need to change one or two CSS properties... and assigning different class names seem too much of overhead for such a minimal job.